# Android AlphaAnimation for different states of StatesListDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-button

I'm trying to accomplis similar to this fade out effect for my buttons.

http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-calculator/demo.html

But I can't really see where to put in my Fade Out animation to accomplish this with my code.

I can not define this with XML as I need the colors to bet programatically from a SQLite Database.

Here's my CustomStatesList:

```
public class CustomStateList extends StateListDrawable {

private int backgroundColor, highlightColor, selectedColor;
private int stateFocused = android.R.attr.state_focused;
private int statePressed = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
private int stateSelected = android.R.attr.state_selected;
private ShapeDrawable mCircleShape, mSquareShape;
private LayerDrawable mLayer;


public CustomStateList(Context mContext, int backgroundColor, int highlightColor, int selectedColor) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.highlightColor = highlightColor;
    this.selectedColor = selectedColor;

    mCircleShape = new ShapeDrawable();
    mCircleShape.setShape(new OvalShape());
    mCircleShape.getPaint().setColor(highlightColor);

    mSquareShape = new ShapeDrawable();
    mSquareShape.setShape(new RectShape());
    mSquareShape.getPaint().setColor(backgroundColor);

    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[] {mSquareShape, mCircleShape};
    mLayer = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    this.addState(new int[] {stateFocused }, mLayer);
    this.addState(new int[] {statePressed }, mLayer);
    this.addState(new int[] {stateSelected }, new ColorDrawable(selectedColor));
    this.addState(new int[]{}, mSquareShape);
}

public int getBackgroundColor() {
    return backgroundColor;
}

public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

public int getHighlightColor() {
    return highlightColor;
}

public void setHighlightColor(int highlightColor) {
    this.highlightColor = highlightColor;
}
```

}

What I want to do is have this animation:

```
final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
```

To be applied to the StatesListDrawable whenever is fading out instead of just instant disappearing. But I have no clue where to apply it! Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you give some more clues? I override the method But I still don't know how to Add an animation to the StatesListDrawable...

Comment: what api level are you using?

Comment: Api lvl 17 but I can go up to 19 if is needed :)

Comment: so use ObjectAnimator in your Drawable,  set property to "alpha" so that the animator would call Drawable.setAlpha method

Comment: Can you make a example? I've tried adding making a Object animator for fade IN and Fade out them adding it to a animator set and starting it whenever the button was in state pressed in onStateChange... but that doesn't works and also crashes the app :(

Comment: this animates the round rect radii in D drawable: http://pastebin.com/rfNpUaxN